# Space to first character after quote broken if full stop [period] used

Tags: bug, markdown

If you quote a number & add a full stop after it, the formatting jumps off to the left.

```
> 1234

> 1234.

> 123456789.

> 1234567891.
```

> 1234

> 1234. 

> 123456789. 

> 1234567891.

It seems it keeps moving left until 10 digits, after which it then works properly again.
Tested on Mac Safari & Chrome, & Windows 10 Edge.

Without the quote it appears broken in the editor, but corrects itself when published.

123456789.

[screenshot in case it's fixed & the above demo disappears.]

[image]

Comment: The problem is not just with quotes, because of the preview problem, so it is misleading to characterize it in the title & 1st part of the post as only being with quotes.

Comment: If it hadn't been for the quotes, I wouldn't have spotted the issue in the first place. Someone had quoted a reference which used a year as the opening 'sentence', adding a full stop after it.

Comment: What matters is what you know about it now. And your comment doesn't address the problem in my last comment.

Comment: @philipxy - I'm going to maintain that it's my question, about my perception of an issue. The quote/not quote derivation was discovered later, so was added later. It's a minor issue that disappears when published.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because when you have a positive number followed by a period, the markdown renders this into an ordered list, e.g.:

5. 5<sup>th</sup> item
6. Another item, the numbering doesn't really matter
7. etc.

So in order to display it without rendering as list, you can trick the markdown by e.g. adding a backslash after the number and before the period:

> 123456789.

Markdown:

```
>123456789\.
```

Comment: So why does it work if you don't quote it?

Comment: @Tetsujin because it's ordinary list item. There is a bug, my answer is just workaround. The bug is that quote markdown does not nest list items properly, it might have even been reported already, I'll check.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not really a bug: blockquotes start with "`> `", not "`>`" (note the space). The version without the space is a kind of fallback syntax, but it doesn't support lists (ordered or unordered), four-space blockquotes, or any other block-level syntax that I'm aware of (except perhaps ```).

Comment: The space is actually unimportant to the issue. I've put one in each line now, same bug.

Comment: I'd think the 'fix' for this may be to assume no-one needs more than 99 list items & change the way it formats after 4 digits rather than 10. It's a bodge, though;) Otherwise it's just one you have to learn, like the first time you discover it takes two spaces & a new line to actually render as a new line.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah, the later makes more sense i.e. learn and apply. :)